# Don't Enable Agora Sevice on Cocos Creator 3.4.1 Version

Tags: agora.io, cocoscreator

Does anybody help me?. I can't start Agora service on cocos creator v3x. But 2x version it's normal.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of looking around and can see that the [last update on Agora's website](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_cocos_creator?platform=Cocos%20Creator#prerequisites) about Cocos Creator was for version 2.4.3.

This seems like it would need a ticket so that the support team can look into it further:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/ticket?platform=All%20Platforms